# What is the meaning of exclamation marks with respect to lists in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

What is the difference between the following type definitions in GraphQL?

1. `[Item]`
2. `[Item!]`
3. `[Item]!`
4. `[Item!]!`

In which cases can the list be empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `[Item]` means that both the list itself as well as its items can be null.
2. `[Item!]` means that the list cannot contain null items, but the list itself can be null.
3. `[Item]!` means that the list can contain null items, but the list itself cannot be null.
4. `[Item!]!` means that both the list itself as well as its items cannot be null.

In all four cases, the list can be empty.